# ContactForm - Send a confirmation mail

Tags: plugin-contactform

How can I send a confirmation Mail to the user who submits the form within the [ContactForm Plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently someone made a plugin that's doing exactly that https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/contact-form-receipts

Answer (score 4):

Make your own little plugin that listens to the plugin's [`contactForm.beforeSend`](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm#the-contactformbeforesend-event) event
and sends the confirmation mail.

Comment: Uuuh. Me making a plugin? Unfortunately not. So I guess its not possible out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Just saw this, it is possible without building a plugin by hacking the standard contactform plugin. In the file contactformservive.php add:

```
$email->cc = array(
    array('name' => $message->fromName, 'email' => $message->replyTo)
);
```

after $email->body

This will send an EXACT copy to the form submitter. It has one drawback that I noticed; the reply address is also the submitter, so if he/she wants to answer that mail it will return to him/herself. You could add a notion in the body with a standard reply address to prevent this.